# Passing object as array in body in proto3

Tags: grpc, proto3

I'm wondering how I can pass an array as the body of the message without having to specify a key. I can easily do:

```
message TypeResponse {
  message Type {
    string ID = 1;
    string Name = 2;
    string Description = 3;
    string IsMobile = 4;
    string IsTablet = 5;
    string IsDesktop = 6;
  }
  repeated Type types = 1;
}
```

That would response with:

```
{
  "types": [
    {
      "ID": 1
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to structure my response as the following to match my REST API:

```
[
    {
      "ID": 1
      ...
    },
    {
      "ID": 2
      ...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proto requires that the top level concept is a message, which spills into the JSON mapping.

Something you could do is just skip the first characters until you reach a `[` character, and then drop the very last character which will be a `]`.  The output format for JSON is specified by the [Proto3 spec](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json), so you can reasonably depend on the format.

Comment: Do you have an example by any chance?

Comment: Without seeing your code or what language you are using I'm afraid not.

Comment: Node.js :-) Don't have much code to show :-/ unless you mean interpret the results before sending back over the pipe? That's easy, I thought you meant in proto itself.